# Find Duplicate Values in the Gridview using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, dom-events, asp.net-ajax

I have a following requirement. I have a Gridview contains two columns:

| Model Name | Model Description |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Model A | Model A Desc | <kbd>Edit</kbd> <kbd>Update</kbd> <kbd>Cancel</kbd> |
| Model B | Model B Desc | <kbd>Edit</kbd> <kbd>Update</kbd> <kbd>Cancel</kbd> |
| Model C | Model C Desc | <kbd>Edit</kbd> <kbd>Update</kbd> <kbd>Cancel</kbd> |

Let's when user click <kbd>Edit</kbd> link on model C then when he type Model B (Replace 'Model C' with 'Model B') then on <kbd>Update</kbd> link I would like to warn the user that Model B already been defined. I would appreciate your help. For your information both `txtModelName` and `txtModelDesc` are template fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can user  inside  of template field and call a function where in there which does all of the checks you need.

If you intend to do it through javascript, I guess you will have to loop through dom entries for grid and validate.